# Import multiple csv at once and add filename column

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm using the elegant *tidyverse* solution provided by leerssej [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once) to read multiple csv's, like so:

```
df <- list.files(path       = "../Data/Raw_1HR",
                 pattern    = "\\.csv$",
                 full.names = T) %>%
map_df(~read.csv(.,
                 skip       = 7,
                 sep        = ",",
                 header     = T,
                 colClasses = "character"))
```

However, I need to add a column to each individual dataframe to denote where it's coming from. This is contained in the filename. Suppose the filenames are `id01_foo.csv`, `id02_foo.csv` etc. where the name is denoted by the first 4 characters (i.e. id01, id02 etc).

How can I incorporate these id's as character columns in the resulting `df` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we name the results of `list.files` and then use `map_dfc(..., .id="filename")`, it'll be a new column of the frame.

```
df <- list.files(path       = "../Data/Raw_1HR",
                 pattern    = "\\.csv$",
                 full.names = T) %>%
setNames(., nm = basename(.)) %>%
map_df(~read.csv(.,
                 skip       = 7,
                 sep        = ",",
                 header     = T,
                 colClasses = "character"),
       .id = "filename")
```

This will name them per the filename (using `basename(.)`), but we could have easily used the whole path with just `setNames(nm = .)`.